# Xcode 7 - Strange cast error that refers to XCUIElement

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7

I've updated my code to XCode 7 and Swift 2.0, now some of my tests fail and I see a list of 40 warnings in the Test build that are completely unrelated with the code they refer to. 
The warning message is:

```
"Cast From 'XCUIElement' to unrelated type 'String' always fails"
```

And this is an example of a row that produces the warning:

```
if let protocolStr = JSON["version"] as? String{
```

I'm not using XC user interface tests yet... so I cannot understand why this code is referring to that class. Any idea?

**Update: November 9** 
With XCode 7.1 the issue is still there.

Comment: I've got this exact issue, will see what I can find.

Comment: To "fix" it I substituted the AnyObject type with [String:AnyObject].

Answer (score 10):

With Xcode 7.1.1
Not fixed but this workaround helped me:

```
if let protocolStr = JSON["version"] as AnyObject as! String {
```

Comment: We ran into the same issue (Xcode 7.2), and your workaround _actually works_ for us too! But I can't reason why. What was your reasoning for casting this way?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the UI Testing module because this only appears to be a problem when writing unit tests.  My guess is there is an extension on `AnyObject` somewhere to add subscripting that returns an XCUIElement as a convenience for writing UI tests.  Something like https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielementquery/1500776-subscript that leaks into AnyObject ...

Answer (score 2):

I think you already fixed your issue, but in case anyone else is looking at this:

The problem is that JSON is of type AnyObject I'm guessing, at it doesn't know that you can index it as a dictionary. If you cast it as  [String : AnyObject] before hand it won't give you an error. (like you noticed)

edit: As for why it's giving you that error specifically, I'm not sure. Probably a bug.

Comment: This cast doesn't work only with the test target. The application target accepts this cast without any problem.

Comment: Nope it didn't work. The issue is still there, and we DON'T have to find a workaround, Apple HAS TO fix this bug.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it was situational for me. And MatterGoal I agree with you, but Apple generally doesn't give a flying f**** what you think they have to do. I've had bugs reported for well over a year they haven't even acknowledged.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was type the key string (“version”) to `NSString` like so:

```
if let protocolStr = JSON["version" as NSString] as? String {
    …
}
```

Comment: you cannot convert to NSString like this anymore

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 7.2, swift 2.2**

Try like this

```
if let protocolStr = JSON.valueForKey("version") as? String{
     //your code
}
```